# In reaction-diffusion processes what is the difference between oscillatory media and excitable media?

Tags: non-linear-systems, complex-systems

What is the basic differences between oscillatory media and excitable media? I know that both comes under reaction-diffusion processes. Where do Turing patterns come in the picture? Can some one give me examples too?

Comment: Oscillatory systems form waves as the reaction products diffuse through space.  Excitable systems exhibit patterns when perturbed, but they always return to the initial state.  This may help: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Reaction-diffusion_systems#Reaction-diffusion_equations.  Alan Turing theorized that two interacting molecules could establish patterns of diffusion if one provided local activation and the other long-range inhibition.  This treatise may help: https://phylogenous.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/alan-turings-reaction-diffusion-model-simplification-of-the-complex/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are no universally accepted defintions of *Turing pattern, excitable* or *oscillatory* medium. This is somewhat understandable as there is no real need for one. All these terms describe very huge classes of phenomena and thus you do not form any statements requiring a precise definitions such as: “If X is an oscillatory medium, then …” That being said:

#### Excitable medium

From *[Zykov – Scholarpedia: Excitable media](http://dx.doi.org/10.4249/scholarpedia.1834):*

> An excitable medium is a dynamical system distributed continuously in space, each elementary segment of which possesses the property of excitability.

Excitablity is generally understood as the property of a system (here, an elementary segment) to yield a huge response to a small perturbation and return back to the previous behaviour afterwards.

A classical example for a excitable system is a patch of forest. You can excite it by tossing a burning match into it, the excitation being a forest fire. The system eventually returns to its previous state when the forest regrows. The corresponding excitable medium would be an entire forest.

#### Oscillatory medium

From *[Pikovsky, Rosenblum, Kurths – Synchronization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511755743),* p. 266:

> An oscillatory medium is an extended system, where each site (element) performs self-sustained oscillations.

As an example, they give is a container in which the [Belousov–Zhabotinsky reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction) happens.

---

Both, excitable and oscillatory media can exhibit spatiotemporal patterns, the former as reaction to an intial excitation, the latter by themselves. In both cases, we need the sites (patches, segments) of the system to communicate with each other either to propagate the excitation or to synchronise the oscillations to some extent.

You can also have media that are both excitable and oscillatory. Here the unexcited state is not a fixed point, but the oscillation. For an example consider an ecosystem where the populations of individual species oscillate due to biological or external rhythms (such as the year) but which also can be excited by external influences yielding beneficial conditions for one species, whose population then explodes.

---

I am no expert on Turing patterns, but the main differences to the patterns exhibited by excitable or oscillatory media is that they temporally stable. If my understanding is correct, they are potential stable states of certain reaction–diffusion systems.